# scroll UISearchBar in a toolbar when Keyboard is appearing in iPad App?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, keyboard, uisearchbar

I read many topics but I cannot find a solution :-( maybe you can help!

In my storyboard (for iPad App) I have the following:
 - a Navigation Controller that is my initial Scene
 - a Segue that opens a View Controller that contains the following hierarchy:
    - Scroll View
      -> Toolbar
          -> BAR Button Item
             -> Search Bar With Prompt
      -> Map View
     - Navigation Item
      -> Bar Button item

My Search Bar is in the bottom toolbar and as a consequence when I click on it the keyboard is displayed and it hides my Search Bar. I would like to scroll up everything to display my Search Bar (Navigation, Map, Toolbar...).

I have registered the Keyboard notifications and implemented the code as described in the IOS documentation

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
```

{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your application might not need or want this behavior.
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

}

When this code is executed, it seems something happens (My map view display a white view instead of the map) and the keyboard is displayed but my Search bar is still invisible.

Is there a issue in my View hierarchy? because it's embedded in a Navigation controller? I'm a little bit lost for this issue. Just a point, before to have a scrollView in my hierarchy I had a simple View, just replaced the simple view with the scroll view because of the issue with the Search Bar.
Your helps will be very appreciated!
Thanks,

Sébastien.

Comment: I have progressed a little bit on the analysis, the issue in the computation of the scrollPoint.
If I use: CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 352.0); it works. Any idea with activeField doesn't return the appropriate value? activeField is a UISearchBar in the bottom toolbar of my App. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, it's because my App is in Landscape mode and the uiSearchBar position is relative to the toolbar.
Below is the fix

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

// Get the Keyboard size
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

// Add to the scroll view a bottom inset equal to height of the keyboard
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your application might not need or want this behavior.
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.width; // in landscape mode need to get width and not height!

// Compute the position of the uiSearchBar in the screen (whole scrollview)
CGPoint realPoint = [_LocateCell convertPoint:_LocateCell.frame.origin toView:self.scrollView];

if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, realPoint) ) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, kbSize.width);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

}